# What's the equivalent of JTextArea.viewToModel for JavaFX's text controls?

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFX, in some text control like TextArea or similar, I want to be able to convert from mouse event coordinates to know exactly which character location is under the mouse. Is there some straightforward way to do that?

In Swing, you can use JTextArea.viewToModel, but I can't find the equivalent in JavaFX yet.

Specifically, I'm trying to find the location in the text (row/column) where mouse events occur. Knowing which side of the char it occurs on would be nice, too, though I don't know if that's supported.

Put another way, I want to decorate the character on mouse over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. It's:

```
TextArea text = ...
HitInfo hit = ((TextAreaSkin) text.getSkin()).getIndex(me);
```

Yes, it's in a com.sun.** package but I don't have a choice about that. I can hope that Oracle will someday make the equivalent public.

isLeading on HitInfo doesn't seem to work: it always returns true. And the insertion/char index are always the same even when they shouldn't be... But, at least I can get the insertion/char index. I suppose I should report bugs for those things but since they're not public APIs they probably won't care.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps coordinates of the mouse events are not necessary. You know that certain mouse events will move the carat (or selection). When you hear one of them inside your textarea, just ask the textarea where the carat wound up.

If that's acceptable, then [getAnchor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#getAnchor%28%29) and [getCaretPosition()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#getCaretPosition%28%29) seem to be what you want.

From the javadoc for getCaretPosition()

> The current position of the caret within the text. The anchor and
>   caretPosition make up the selection range.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work. As I mentioned at the end of my post, I want to do it on mouse over, so the caret will not have moved.

Comment: oops. Somehow I read it and got the idea of decorating the selected text, not a character on mouse-over. Probably a case of thinking I know what it will say and not actually reading to the end of the sentence... Curious use case you have... why decorate a single character?